# How to correctly capture a data-rel from a clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a table that automatically populates a list of users, I am trying to capture the data-rel attribute so I can query the database, retrieve the user data and show it. The issue that I am not being able to resolve is that when I try to capture the data-rel value I have as a result: undefined.

Here is an example of how the HTML is rendered on the page

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="linkshowuser" data-rel="531fe2cef46de62a24a0a8ab" title="Show Details">user2</a>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="linkshowuser" data-rel="531fe513dfd24a9d24ebb0c5" title="Show Details">user2</a>
</td>
```

To capture the click I use the following event on the BackboneView

```
// ### Details View (DV) ###    
'click td a.linkshowuser': 'DV_Show'
```

so far so good, this is working on the sense that I correctly get the click identified and the function DV_Show is triggered

```
DV_Show: function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data('rel');
  console.log (id);
}
```

The only thing I am trying to do right now i making sure that I get the data-rel information  on the id variable, but this is not happening.

the output that I am getting from the console is: undefined, and I think that this is because this is not pointing to the link, but I dont know the right way to do it.

I have seen other questions about this on Stackoverflow and all of them use the THIS keyword, but I believe that the difference may be that I have it inside a Backbone View so THIS may be pointing somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get element from `event.currentTarget` and `event` is passed to your callback function

```
DV_Show: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('rel');
  console.log (id);
}
```

Your example doesn't work because Backbone uses `this` variable for binding it to the view itself.

Comment: Great, it is working as I was expecting. I tough that the THIS may be the problem but did not know how to correct it. Thanks for the answer